# C: error C2784: 'bool std::operator <

Tags: c++

I use Visual Studio 2010.

```
struct SPoint
{
    int id;
    int X;
    int Y;
};
////////////////
vector<SPoint> points;
vector<SPoint> chosen;
////////////////
void print_vect(const vector<SPoint> & vect)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vect.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << vect[i].id << " (" << vect[i].X << "," << vect[i].Y << ")"<<endl;               
    }               
    cout << endl;   
}
////////////////
print_vect(points);
```

The compiler shows:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\algorithm(4674): error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::move_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'SPoint'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\iterator(371) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
```

I modeled this in a separate project:

```
struct SPoint
{   
    int X;
    int Y;
};

vector<SPoint> points;
vector<SPoint> selected;

void print_vector(const vector<SPoint> & points) {    
    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << '('<<points[i].X <<',' <<points[i].Y <<')'<< endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
int main ()
{
    SPoint temp = {0, 0};
    for (int i = 0; i < 11;i++)
    {
        temp.X = i;
        temp.Y = i;
        points.push_back(temp);
    }
    for (int i = 5; i< 11;i++)
    {
        temp.X = i;
        temp.Y = i;
        selected.push_back(temp);
    }

    print_vector(points);       
    system ("pause" );
  return 0;
}
```

It works perfectly.
I tried to find something on this problem. They say, the compiler can't compare two objects. Add "<" method to your class. But I'm studying procedural programming so far.
Then, my trial example works. Why and what to do?

Comment: which line does the error occur on ?

Comment: Not being able to deduce the parameter from `SPoint` makes it sound like it's misinterpreting `vector<SPoint>`. Ensure `<vector>` is included and some form of using is done before that.

Comment: Compiles okay? http://ideone.com/SxLmKd `bool std::operator <` makes me thing you're not showing us the code, and in the code you're not showing us you have `<` instead of `<<`.

Comment: Maybe this can show some light? https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=8CDFFBA921B002FE!120&authkey=!AMBmkqYFTRqPzUw

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `set_difference` calls `operator<` to compare elements in points/chosen:

```
set_difference(points.begin(), points.end(),
    chosen.begin(), chosen.end(), back_inserter(cleared));
```

To make your code compile, you need to overload `operator<` for SPoint type, for example:

```
bool operator<(const SPoint& lhs, const SPoint& rhs)
{
  return lhs.id < rhs.id;
}
```

Comment: Where do you see the `set_difference` call?

Comment: he puts it in skydrive....  https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=8cdffba921b002fe&id=8CDFFBA921B002FE%21121

Comment: @Kifsif please update your question with relative code